# Prevent users from encrypting their home folders

Tags: 12.04, server, encryption, ecryptfs

How can I prevent users from encrypting their home folder on a server inside our company without removing the respective packages?

Are there any policies I can enable to prevent this?

Edit: the reason is that employees leaving should not leave data behind in encrypted form on this machine. They have the opportunity to use encryption on their personal workstation to some extent. Those users do not have super user powers.

Comment: Why do you want that, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: what privileges do these employees require, what is their job on the servers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the `ecryptfs-utils` package, then the easiest way to do this would be to remove the setuid bit on `/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private`.

You should use a dpkg state override to make this setting persistent, like so:

```
dpkg-statoverride --add root root 0700 /sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private
```

This will ensure that `ecryptfs-setup-private` and `ecryptfs-mount-private` fail with an EPERM error for non-root users.

If this becomes a popular request, we could easily add this as a debconf question/option in the package.